# Issue with Intellisense for VSCode for Unity on Ubuntu 18.04LTS

Tags: c#, .net, unity-game-engine, visual-studio-code, ubuntu-18.04

**Problem**

I am trying to use Unity on Ubuntu 18.04 using Visual Studio Code.
To set it up, I followed the steps put here:
https://medium.com/@sami1592/set-up-visual-studio-code-for-unity-in-linux-69b7f4352e0b
Some additional steps not mentioned in the article:

1. I installed vscode with snap (from the software center) and redirected Unity's external coding program to it.
2. I ran the installation commands while logged in as an administrator using *su*.

On the first day I was using this, I had no problems; Intellisense worked perfectly.
The next day, after I powered on my computer and opened my project, I found that Intellisense stopped working well.
VSCode output this error in the Omnisharp terminal:

> Starting OmniSharp server at 11/4/2020, 4:51:19 PM
> Target: /home/fakeusername/Code/FakeProjectName/FakeProjectName.sln
>
> OmniSharp server started.
> Path: /home/fakeusername/.vscode/extensions/ms-dotnettools.csharp-1.23.5/.omnisharp/1.37.3/run
> PID: 3364
>
> Starting OmniSharp on ubuntu 18.4 (x64) info: OmniSharp.Services.DotNetCliService
> DotNetPath set to dotnet info: OmniSharp.MSBuild.Discovery.MSBuildLocator
> Located 1 MSBuild instance(s)
> 1: StandAlone 16.8.0 - "/home/fakeusername/.vscode/extensions/ms-dotnettools.csharp-1.23.5/.omnisharp/1.37.3/omnisharp/.msbuild/Current/Bin"
> info: OmniSharp.MSBuild.Discovery.MSBuildLocator
> MSBUILD_EXE_PATH environment variable set to '/home/fakeusername/.vscode/extensions/ms-dotnettools.csharp-1.23.5/.omnisharp/1.37.3/omnisharp/.msbuild/Current/Bin/MSBuild.exe'
> info: OmniSharp.MSBuild.Discovery.MSBuildLocator
> Registered MSBuild instance: StandAlone 16.8.0 - "/home/fakeusername/.vscode/extensions/ms-dotnettools.csharp-1.23.5/.omnisharp/1.37.3/omnisharp/.msbuild/Current/Bin"
> CscToolExe = csc.exe
> MSBuildToolsPath = /home/fakeusername/.vscode/extensions/ms-dotnettools.csharp-1.23.5/.omnisharp/1.37.3/omnisharp/.msbuild/Current/Bin
> CscToolPath = /home/fakeusername/.vscode/extensions/ms-dotnettools.csharp-1.23.5/.omnisharp/1.37.3/omnisharp/.msbuild/Current/Bin/Roslyn
> BypassFrameworkInstallChecks = true
> MSBuildExtensionsPath = /home/fakeusername/.vscode/extensions/ms-dotnettools.csharp-1.23.5/.omnisharp/1.37.3/omnisharp/.msbuild
> info: OmniSharp.Cake.CakeProjectSystem
> Detecting Cake files in '/home/fakeusername/Code/FakeProjectName'. info:
> OmniSharp.Cake.CakeProjectSystem
> Could not find any Cake files info: OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectSystem
> Detecting projects in '/home/fakeusername/Code/FakeProjectName/FakeProjectName.sln'. info:
> OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectManager
> Queue project update for '/home/fakeusername/Code/FakeProjectName/Assembly-CSharp.csproj'
> info: OmniSharp.Script.ScriptProjectSystem
> Detecting CSX files in '/home/fakeusername/Code/FakeProjectName'. info:
> OmniSharp.Script.ScriptProjectSystem
> Could not find any CSX files info: OmniSharp.WorkspaceInitializer
> Invoking Workspace Options Provider: OmniSharp.Roslyn.CSharp.Services.CSharpFormattingWorkspaceOptionsProvider,
> Order: 0 info: OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectManager
> Loading project: /home/fakeusername/Code/FakeProjectName/Assembly-CSharp.csproj info:
> OmniSharp.WorkspaceInitializer
> Invoking Workspace Options Provider: OmniSharp.Roslyn.CSharp.Services.Completion.CompletionOptionsProvider,
> Order: 0 info: OmniSharp.WorkspaceInitializer
> Invoking Workspace Options Provider: OmniSharp.Roslyn.CSharp.Services.RenameWorkspaceOptionsProvider,
> Order: 100 info: OmniSharp.WorkspaceInitializer
> Invoking Workspace Options Provider: OmniSharp.Roslyn.CSharp.Services.ImplementTypeWorkspaceOptionsProvider,
> Order: 110 info: OmniSharp.WorkspaceInitializer
> Invoking Workspace Options Provider: OmniSharp.Roslyn.CSharp.Services.BlockStructureWorkspaceOptionsProvider,
> Order: 140 info: OmniSharp.WorkspaceInitializer
> Configuration finished. info: OmniSharp.Stdio.Host
> Omnisharp server running using Stdio at location '/home/fakeusername/Code/FakeProjectName' on host 3236. fail:
> OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectLoader
> The reference assemblies for .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.1 were not found. To resolve this, install the Developer Pack (SDK/Targeting
> Pack) for this framework version or retarget your application. You can
> download .NET Framework Developer Packs at
> https://aka.ms/msbuild/developerpacks [warn]:
> OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectManager
> Failed to load project file '/home/fakeusername/Code/FakeProjectName/Assembly-CSharp.csproj'.
> /home/fakeusername/Code/FakeProjectName/Assembly-CSharp.csproj
> /home/fakeusername/.vscode/extensions/ms-dotnettools.csharp-1.23.5/.omnisharp/1.37.3/omnisharp/.msbuild/Current/Bin/Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(1180,5):
> Error: The reference assemblies for .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.1 were
> not found. To resolve this, install the Developer Pack (SDK/Targeting
> Pack) for this framework version or retarget your application. You can
> download .NET Framework Developer Packs at
> https://aka.ms/msbuild/developerpacks
>
> Attempted to update project that is not loaded: /home/fakeusername/Code/FakeProjectName/Assembly-CSharp.csproj

**What I've tried**

- Reinstalling Mono:
  I repeated the installation steps for 18.04 specified here: https://www.mono-project.com/download/stable/#download-lin
  I tried to a number of times, sometime uninstalling mono-devel first.
  After doing so, I would test the installation with the Hello World example on this page, which always worked: https://www.mono-project.com/docs/getting-started/mono-basics/
- Reinstalling .NET Core SDK:
  I repeated the installation steps for 18.04 specified here, following the steps under '18.04' and the corresponding 'Install the SDK': https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/install/linux-ubuntu#1804-
  I first did this without any un-installation, and it had no effect.
  I then did it after removing the *'usr/share/dotnet'* and *'home/fakeusername/.dotnet'* directories. This did not fix the issue, and an additional problem: the console no longer recognized the *dotnet* command in the terminal; it showed the error:

> Command 'dotnet' not found, but can be installed with:
> sudo snap install dotnet-sdk

Despite this issue and the new one that arose later, I have not had any issues running the Unity game itself.